# Equal data in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

If the text_checkin is equal to **reserve from** (the reserve from is the column in my table). Again if the text_checkin is equal to column reservefrom, the browser will be echo "same date", it works in the first row, but i enter same data in second row in **reservefrom** column the data will be inserted even the reservefrom column is equal to text_checkin.

Here's the structure:

```
$reservation = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from reservation");

    //if submit is clicked
    $checkin = $_POST['text_checkin'];

    $sqlroom3 = "SELECT * FROM reservation";
    $resultroom3 = mysqli_query($db, $sqlroom3);
    $valuesroom3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultroom3);
    $num_rowsroom3 = $valuesroom3['reservefrom'];

    if(isset($_POST['submitBtn']) && $row = mysqli_fetch_array($reservation))
    {
        if($row['reservefrom'] == $checkin) 
        {
            echo "asdasd";
        }
        else
        {
        $lastname = $_POST['text_lastname'];
        $firstname = $_POST['text_firstname'];
        $address = $_POST['text_address'];
        $tnumber = $_POST['text_tnumber'];
        $cnumber = $_POST['text_cnumber'];
        $email = $_POST['text_email'];
        $checkin = $_POST['text_checkin'];
        $checkout = $_POST['text_checkout'];
        $room = $_POST['text_room'];
        $tour = $_POST['text_tour'];
        $guest = $_POST['text_guest'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO reservation (lastname, firstname, homeaddress, telephonenumber, cellphonenumber, email, reservefrom, reserveto, room, tour, guestnumber) values ('$lastname', '$firstname', '$address', '$tnumber', '$cnumber', '$email', '$checkin', '$checkout', '$room', '$tour', '$guest')";
        mysqli_query($db, $query);
        echo "Data Submitted!";
    }
    }
```

Comment: It's worth noting that your code is *wide open* to **SQL injection**.  You're essentially executing any code your users send you.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman please give me example of the syntax in new code. Thanks

Comment: @DaveSpencer There's several links in that comment which will explain in more detail. The comments on those pages explain further.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your logic.
You have multiples rows and you are only checking if the text_checkin is equal to the first $row['reservefrom'].
Thats y the second row always inserts.

You may change your query to return only desired row, or do a loop to check all rows from your table.